# Thrust vector placement for an object affected by gravity to reach a target direction vector

Tags: gravity, acceleration, vectors

The problem occurred when I tried to calculate the thrust vector angle of a missile for it to fly into a certain direction. Without gravity this would be a really simple problem, but including gravity I can't seem to work this equation out.

Given:

- thrust in $m \over s²$ (mass is known)
- acceleration due to gravity
- target direction

written as vectors, we have

$$
\overrightarrow {thrust} = l \angle ? \\
\overrightarrow {gravityAcceleration} = 9.81 \angle {2 \over 3} \pi \\
\overrightarrow {target} = ? \angle direction
$$

So the two unknown factors in this equation are

- the angle of the thrust vector
- the length of the target direction vector (which is irrelevant, since it only gives the direction)

What I've tried:

### Solving it using a simple equation system

for this try I used following example parameters:

$$
\overrightarrow {thrust} = 30 {m \over s^2} \angle \alpha \\
\overrightarrow {gravityAcceleration} = 9.81 \angle {2 \over 3} \pi \\
\overrightarrow {target} = l \angle {3 \over 4} \pi
$$

calculation:

$$
\overrightarrow {target} = \overrightarrow {thrust} + \overrightarrow {gravityAcceleration}
$$

write using Cartesian form:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos({3 \over 4} \pi) * l \\
\sin({3 \over 4} \pi) * l
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
-9.81
\end{bmatrix} + 
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\alpha) * 30 \\
\sin(\alpha) * 30
\end{bmatrix}
$$

get simple equations

$$
0 = \cos(\alpha) * 30 - \cos \bigg ({3 \over 4} \pi \bigg ) * l
$$

$$
9.81 = \sin(\alpha) * 30 - \sin \bigg ({3 \over 4} \pi \bigg ) * l
$$

solving the first equation for `l`, we get

$$
l = {\cos (\alpha) * 30 \over \cos \bigg ( {3 \over 4} \pi \bigg )}
$$

putting this into the second equation and simplifying it, the furthest I got was

$$
-9.81 = {sin \bigg ( {3 \over 4} \pi \bigg ) * \cos (\alpha) * 30 \over \cos \bigg ( {3 \over 4} \pi \bigg )} - \sin(\alpha) * 30
$$

So now I have an equation with only one variable, but trying to solve for $\alpha$ seems impossible to me. Even asking WolframAlpha or similar programs for a solution got me formulas that are only valid for very specific input parameters.

So what I'm looking for would be a formula for calculating the thrust vector angle, given the gravity vector and the direction the object should fly in.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've updated my comment, hopefully it is more obvious now